# R Predict using multiple models

Tags: r, regression, glm

I am new to R and trying to predict outcomes on a dataset using 4 different GLM's.  I have tried running as one large model and while I do get results the model doesn't converge properly and I end up with N/A's.  I therefore have four models:

```
model_team <- glm(mydata$OUT ~ TEAM + OPPONENT, family = "binomial",data =      mydata )

model_conf <- glm(mydata$OUT ~ TCONF + OCONF, family = "binomial",data = mydata)

model_tstats <- glm(mydata$OUT ~ TPace + TORtg + TFTr + T3PAr + TTS. + TTRB. + TAST. + TSTL. + TBLK. + TeFG. + TTOV. + TORB. + TFT.FGA, family = "binomial",data = mydata)

model_ostats<- glm(mydata$OUT ~ OPace + OORtg + OFTr + O3PAr + OTS. + OTRB. + OAST. + OSTL. + OBLK. + OeFG. + OTOV. + OORB. + OFT.FGA, family = "binomial",data = mydata)
```

I then want to predict the outcomes using a different data set using the four models

```
predict(model_team, model_conf, model_tstats, model_ostats, fix, level = 0.95, type = "probs")
```

Is there a way to use all four models with joining them into one large set?

Comment: You could try `glmnet` and use `Lasso` regularization, so it can do variable selection for you. It also has tools for `cross-validation`.

Comment: How would `glm(OUT ~  ., data = mydata ,family = "binomial")` be different from what you are suggesting with "joining all four models". `OUT ~ .` implies using all available independent variable, e.g. `glm(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars,family=gaussian())`

Comment: Instead of worrying about combining models, ranking models (AIC/BIC) and variable importance @Fernando's suggestion is perfect since `Lasso` algorithm completes variable selection and model fitting in one step. Also, it yields a parsimonious(simple)  model with irrelevant variables with zero beta coefficients than a small but non-zero value from other algorithms. Exploring examples from `install.packages("glmnet",dep=TRUE);?cv.glmnet` would greatly help

Answer (score -3):

I don't really understand why you are trying to do what you are doing. I also don't have any example data that is a representation of the data you are working with. However, below is an example of how you could combine multiple GLMs into one using the resulting coefficients. Note that this will not work well if you have multicollinearity between the variables in your dataset.

```
# I used the iris dataset for my example
head(iris)

# Run several models
model1 <- glm(data = iris, Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)
model2 <- glm(data = iris, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length)
model3 <- glm(data = iris, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width)

# Get combined intercept
intercept <- mean(
  coef(model1)['(Intercept)'],
  coef(model2)['(Intercept)'],
  coef(model3)['(Intercept)'])

# Extract coefficients
coefs <- as.matrix(
  c(coef(model1)[2],
    coef(model2)[2],
    coef(model3)[2])

# Get the feature values for the predictions
ds <- as.matrix(iris[,c('Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')])
# Linear algebra: Matrix-multiply values with coefficients
prediction <- ds %*% coefs + intercept

# Let's look at the results
plot(iris$Petal.Length, prediction)
```

Comment: Not sure why people down-vote this.
Could you point out to me what you dislike about my answer please?

Comment: Where did this method for combining models come from? Does it have a statistical foundation? Taking the mean intercept and reusing for all models seems odd. It's always after to use `predict()` rather that trying to do the matrix multiplication yourself especially when you have categorical variables in your model.

Comment: Extracting coefficients and doing matrix multiplication is a common approach to productionise models, e.g. when you want to continuously score new observations quickly in a large infrastructure. Model averaging is common as well. As for categorical variables, they should be dummy variables or WoE transformed before using them in the model. Anyway, I considered since this is stackoverflow, not cross-validated, that the focus of the question was to get a working approach to do what the op wanted to do, not to argue that they should not do it?

Comment: examples for coefficient extraction: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89268/calculating-point-estimates-from-model-averaged-parameters and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157601/how-does-one-extract-the-final-equation-from-glm-poisson-model

Comment: references on model averaging and matrix multiplication: https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta244/Handouts/press.pdf and http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1420-9101.2010.02210.x/full